# obtain different values in star rating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

how are you. I'm implementing a rating at IONIC, although this is basically angular. I want to get the value for each category. if I qualify rubric "animals" I want to get the value I selected. if I qualify "cars" I want to get the value I selected.

My problem is that I always get the same value for both categories. What can I do?. I want to know what is the best solution because then I think creating dynamic code and do not want to repeat code in n categories.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1PomwzklGD2Y8esbsnxT?p=preview

**HTML**

```
What do you think about the animals?
<ionic-ratings ratingsobj='ratingsObject'></ionic-ratings>
What do you think about the cars??
<ionic-ratings ratingsobj='ratingsObject'></ionic-ratings>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$scope.ratingsObject = {
 iconOn: 'ion-ios-star', //Optional
 iconOff: 'ion-ios-star-outline',  //Optional
 iconOnColor: 'rgb(200, 200, 100)',  //Optional
 iconOffColor: 'rgb(200, 100, 100)', //Optional
 rating: 4,  //Optional
 minRating: 1, //Optional
 readOnly:false, //Optional
 callback: function(rating) {  //Mandatory    
 $scope.ratingsCallback(rating);
 }
};

$scope.ratingsCallback = function(rating) {
 $scope.cars=rating;
 $scope.animals=rating;
 console.log('Selected rating is : ', rating);

 //is the same value :(
 console.log("animals: "+$scope.animals);
 console.log("cars: "+$scope.cars);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use another ionic rating library like [this one](https://github.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating) which enables the use of `ng-model`. So you can use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) with an array as a model, and then bind the `<rating>` directive to a property automatically updated when user set the rating.

Here below is your example adapted to use that lib and made dynamic:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic.rating'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myTitle = 'IONIC RATINGS DEMO';

  $scope.categories = [{
    name: "animals",
    question: "What do you think about the animals?",
    rating: 0
  }, {
    name: "cars",
    question: "What do you think about the cars?",
    rating: 0
  }, {
    name: "flowers",
    question: "What do you think about the flowers?",
    rating: 0
  }];

  $scope.rating = {};
  $scope.rating.max = 5;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating/master/ionic-rating.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/fraserxu/ionic-rating/master/ionic-rating.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-view>
    <h1 class="text-center">{{myTitle}}</h1>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="category in categories">
        {{category.question}}
        <rating ng-model="category.rating" max="rating.max"></rating>
      </div>
    </div>

    <pre>categories = {{categories|json}}</pre>
  </ion-view>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S.: in the `<pre>` tag is shown the model only for debug and demo.